# how can I create UIlabel animation so that change in text will be shown like speedometer or crypto currency wallet balance? please refer Video

Tags: ios, swift

[Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/173HsyYUFC0TMVXxV-CREhzzaslrsHYd0/view?usp=sharing)

how can I create UIlabel animation so that change in text will be shown like speedometer or crypto currency wallet balance? please refer Video.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called `SpringText` that is doing exactly what you are looking for. [GitHub - SpringText](https://github.com/comcxx11/SpringText)